# Mailchimp rss image spacing

Tags: rss, mailchimp

I am trying to adjust the spacing above and below the image in a Mailchimp rss feed email. Whatever I try I have far too much space between the heading and the image and no spage between the bottom of the image and the excerpt text. Not helped by thefact that the preview doesn't include the image so I am having to send endless tests to myself.

```
*|RSSITEMS:|*
<h2 class="mc-toc-title" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin:0px; padding:0px;">*|RSSITEM:TITLE|*</h2>

<span style="margin:0px 0px 12px 0px;"><a href="*|RSSITEM:URL|*" target="_blank">*|RSSITEM:IMAGE|*</a></span>
<br/><br/>
<span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; marginn:12px 0 0 0;"><br/>*|RSSITEM:CONTENT|*&nbsp;<a href="*|RSSITEM:URL|*" target="_blank">[Read&nbsp;more&nbsp;.&nbsp;.&nbsp;.]</a></span><br/>
<br/><hr/>
*|END:RSSITEMS|*
```

Also is it possible to make the footer come to full width, at the moment it is indented left and right?

Thanks